# How to retrieve data from 2 columns combined in database and display in drop down list?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a table --> class - id, date, time, remark
In my asp.net application, i want to display date + time together in the drop down list.
NOTE: Time is in a string format (i.e 9:00 - 11:00, 12:30 - 1:00)
I  am not sure if this is doable. Please advise me.

Currently, i only manage to display date. Please see code below

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select id,Date,Time from class", con);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter dA = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        dA.Fill(dt);
        dd1.DataSource = dt;
        dd1.DataTextField = "Date"; //want to show date and time
        dd1.DataValueField = "id";
        dd1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
```

Expected Results - "12/01/2019 9:00-11:00"

Comment: If you can specify field names, Try This.

"Select id, concat(Date,Time) from class"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using SQL server, you could modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT ID, CONVERT(char(10), Date, 103) + ' ' + Time [Date]
FROM class
```

And use the column Date as your DataTextField

Answer (score 0):

Tried below code and its working now:

```
con.Open();
sql = @ "SELECT Date + ' ' + Time AS Session, id, remark FROM class ORDER BY Session ASC;";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter dA = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
dA.Fill(dt);
dd1.DataSource = dt;
dd1.DataTextField = "Session";
dd1.DataValueField = "id";
dd1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Database you are using?

In SQL Server, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date , 3) + ' ' + Time AS Date 
FROM class
```

Other code will the remain same.